# descriptor indexing: difference between 2 similar fields

Tags: vulkan

Normally, when using regular descriptor sets, the field VkDescriptorSetLayoutBinding::descriptorCount  denotes the array count of the binding.
https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.2-extensions/man/html/VkDescriptorSetLayoutBinding.html

When using DescriptorIndexing feature, with variable-size arrays, the field VkDescriptorSetVariableDescriptorCountAllocateInfo::pDescriptorCounts denotes "the number of descriptors in the variable count descriptor binding in the corresponding descriptor set layout".
https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.2-extensions/man/html/VkDescriptorSetVariableDescriptorCountAllocateInfo.html

So, when using DescriptorIndexing, it seems that both VkDescriptorSetLayoutBinding::descriptorCount and VkDescriptorSetVariableDescriptorCountAllocateInfo::pDescriptorCounts do a similar thing.

In this latter case, what is the difference between these 2 fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The descriptor indexing feature allows (if the implementation lets you) the highest numbered descriptor binding in a descriptor set layout to be designated as a "variable-sized descriptor". This is specified by the array of flags provided by the `VkDescriptorSetLayoutBindingFlagsCreateInfo` structure provided to `VkDescriptorSetLayoutCreateInfo`. Giving the highest descriptor the `VK_DESCRIPTOR_BINDING_VARIABLE_DESCRIPTOR_COUNT_BIT` flag activates this feature. Note that this means that, for any given descriptor set, there will be precisely one descriptor that has a variable layout: the last one.

Variable-sized descriptors work like this. At descriptor set allocation time, you will provide the actual number of descriptors for each set being allocated using the `VkDescriptorSetVariableDescriptorCountAllocateInfo` structure with `VkDescriptorSetAllocateInfo`. This struct contains an array of descriptor counts, one entry each for each set you're allocating. Since each set can have at most only one variable-sized descriptor, the `pDescriptorCounts`  contains one count for each set (if that set has a variable-sized descriptor).

The `descriptorCount` for a variable-sized descriptor still matters. It defines the upper-bound for the variable descriptor: the maximum number of descriptors you will allocate.

The point of this feature is to allow for cases where you might have 1,000 samplers in an array, but you know that for right now, you only need 250. So instead of allocating a bunch of samplers you don't need, you allocate 250. When the time comes that you need more, then you're going to have to allocate a whole new descriptor set (probably from a larger pool) to accommodate this need.